# property value not showing with <s:if>

Tags: struts2

contains the date of birth(date value), but it is not showing dob value is there any mistake in

```
 <s:if>
```

tag

```
<s:if test="blist[0].dob!=null && blist[0].dob!=''">
   <div class="info">
              <div class="title">
                   Birthday
              </div>
      <div class="value">
         <s:property value="blist[0].dob" />
      </div>
   </div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: You can always debug the jsp or simply try   <s:property value="blist[0]" /> before if tag. then check  <s:property value="blist[0].dob" /> is not null or empty (outside if tag)(i am assuming dob is string).

Comment: @AshishGupta <s:property value="blist[0].dob" />is showing value properly and dob is java.sql.Date type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need that `blist[0].dob != ''` check, checking against `null` is enough.
But if you really want to do that use `toString` method to compare it with blank.

```
<s:if test="blist[0].dob != null && blist[0].dob.toString() != ''">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      Birthday
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <s:property value="blist[0].dob" />
    </div>
  </div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: ksandr M  It required for displaying  <div class="title">Birthday</div>

Comment: Can you tell me from where get that toString() can use in s:if

Comment: Are you asking where `toString` method comes from? If so then from `java.lang.Object`. :)

Comment: NO from which doc/tutorial u get